# Android memory test

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

This may be a stupid question but i can't seem to find alot of specific information on the internet.

Lets say i have 2 activities: MainActivity & Secondactivity.
The mainactivity has a button to go to the secondactivity.
The second activity has a button that goes back to the
main activity (very simple code below).

I am trying to understand android memory management and that's why i'm doing this test.

My question:

When i constantly go back and forth between the activities, while looking at the memory graph in Android studio, i can see a blue graph that never goes back down to it's allocated memory that it had on startup of the application. 
Do i have a memory leak? (Probably not cause this is basic code). But then why does it never go back to it's original allocated memory at the beginning?

The mainactivity has only this method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i(null, "test");
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

While the SecondAcitivity just goes back to the first one and creates a few Buttons

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button btnTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i(null, "test");
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: nope,i don't use that. Didn't touch the manifest file

Comment: The code that i pasted the question is the only code in the app , it's very basic, there is no custom backstack implementation

Comment: When you push the back button, your activity gets destroyed and you go to the previous activity. I also wrote the finish() statement in the onClick methods to make sure they get destroyed so isn't it the same thing ? I'm creating new instances on purpose. But the heap should go to the the original allocated memory value i had at startup after a while cause of the garbage collection right?

Comment: My bad, forget about that part -- for some reason I didn't see the `finish()`... but I think it has to do with the `finish()` not completely deleting the `Activity`. I've heard that `onDestroy` being called does not indicate that the object was lost, and that Android keeps the instance for a while in case it is created again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was using genymotion as an emulator.
You should use a real device for memory analysis, also the older memory monitor is more precise.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a memory leak in your code. The reason for the increase in allocated memory is because your app will use some in order to transfer to different activities. But, if you continue to run this code forever, you will see sudden drops, I have drawn this out:

[image]

Everytime Garbage Collection occurs, the allocated memory will go down. If, however, you have a memory leak, that means that GC will not be able to get rid of certain objects. For this, you would see a **trend line** with a general increase, until an out of memory error occurs.

### How can you test this?

I suggest you make it so that the intents are called in the `onCreate` for an infinite loop of back-and-forth activities. Unless you get an `OutOfMemory` error, you probably don't have a memory leak.

From the [developer guide:](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)

> As you allocate more objects in your app, you will force a periodic
>   garbage collection, creating little "hiccups" in the user experience.
>   The concurrent garbage collector introduced in Android 2.3 helps, but
>   unnecessary work should always be avoided.

Comment: I also got a graph with hiccups, but it just keeps rising, and the point  right after garbage collection is each time higher than the previous point after garbage collection. Kinda hard to explain. I hope you know what i mean

Comment: @user2395334 Those hiccups may not be the garbage collection, rather, they may be times when objects are unreferenced. If it is the garbage collection, it would be a memory leak, but I doubt that. Let me know of that was useful

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I can see the GC_FOR_ALLOC freed message for some of these bigger hiccups, but every time when that happens it clears only a small part of the memory. if i switch activities for a long time i get 10 mb allocated memory for example, and garbage collection brings it down to 8 mb. But the app at startup had 2.77 Mb allocated so why does it bring it down to 8 instead of +-2.77? to me that seems like a leak of 7.33 mb

Comment: @user2395334 Try FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT , and tell me what happens

Comment: Why? There is no other activity in the stack because i call finish() each time an activity is closed...

Comment: No because it makes no sense . reorder to front just puts the to be launched activity up front while it's already up front since there's only 1 activity (the other one is finished explicitly)

Comment: @user2395334 Did you figure it out?

Comment: I used genymotion as an emulator. A real device should be used to do memory analysis. That was the problem

Comment: @user2395334 Ohh, that explains it. You should add an answer in case anyone else has the same problem :)

Comment: @user2395334 No worries ;) +1d your answer

Answer (score -1):

The blue graph is the amount of memory allocated.

### Why the allocated memory increases

When you go back and forth between the two activities, your application is being allocated memory to create new activities.

### Why doesn't the allocated memory decrease

It does not decrease because memories are freed during garbage collection. Dalvikvm will determine when a garbage collection should occur therefore it is possible for garbage collection to not occur for an extended period of time. You can continue going back and forth between the two activities to increase the allocated memory and once the allocated memory is large enough you should see a sudden drop in the amount of allocated memory.

### Why is there a sudden drop in allocated memory

The allocated memory are freed when a garbage collection happens. If you take a look at logcat in android studio, the sudden drop in allocated memory should be accompanied by a Dalvikvm GC_something freed message. This means that a garbage collection has occured and memories are freed. You can observe this happening by clicking the initiate GC button (left of the blue graph) to manually trigger garbage collection.

Comment: yes there are drops but it's doesn't drop all the way back to the initial allocated memory at startup and that's why i don't understand...

Answer (score -1):

It's just a matter of garbage collection (GC). Even if you write minimum code, the framework might perform a lot of work behind the scenes. You are in fact explicitly creating a few objects on each click.

Here is the memory graph where you can see the effect of GC.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah but you can see that your graph stays the same in general, my graph rises and i don't know why. There isn't any memory leak since this code with the two activities is very simple and there are no references that keep objects alive as far as i know

Comment: I added a picture, please take a look

Comment: His graph is generally rising